# Скачивание больших файлов на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, видео, download

и так, хочу скачивать видеофайлы с площадок(нет не YouTube), размер файлов от 300мб до 4гб

скачиваю в данный момент на своем компьютере следующим образом:

```
def downloader(user_id: int):
    name = f"./cached_mov/{user_id}_{int(time.time())}.mp4"

    with requests.get(link, headers=HEADERS, stream=True) as response:
        with open(name, 'wb') as mov:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 ** 2):
                mov.write(chunk)

    return name
```

на своём компьютере качается без проблем, но оно качается сначала в оперативную память, а тут её 16гб и соответственно ошибок нет, на сервере же её 1гб, поэтому происходят ошибки.

Хотелось бы скачивать и записывать как то по частям в 20-50 мб за раз, гуглил, выдывало именно этот код, что я предоставил выше, либо же черезе `shutil` который тоже записывал сначала в оперативку

Comment: А скачиваете вы один файл одновременно или много? Может уменьшить `chunk_size` попробовать для начала.

Comment: скачиваю один файл

Answer (score 1):

этот код пишет сразу в файл, но с буферизацией. сделай `mov.flush()` если хочется принудительно сбросить буфер на диск.

chunk_size это размер скаченного блока. тут 1 мегабайт.

Comment: Ну или вообще открывать файл с параметром `buffering=0`. Но вообще файловый буфер обычно совпадает с размером блока файловой системы, а он довольно маленький, скорее всего дело не в записи в файл, а в стриме скачки.

Comment: по вашим советам, изменил код на такой

`with requests.get(link, headers=HEADERS, stream=True) as response:
        with open(name, 'wb', buffering=0) as mov:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 ** 2):
                mov.write(chunk)
                mov.flush()`

использование памяти с 56мб выросло до 320 +- и не идёт выше, но файл качается успешно, чтобы оно потребляло меньше, стоит уменьшить chunk_size?

Comment: flush не нужен при buffering=0. попробуй оставить что-то одно